# Migration from Jira to Azure DevOps using Solidify tool

Tags: azure-devops, migration, jira

I am trying to move my tickets from Jira to Azure DevOps using the [Solidify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solidify.jira-devops-migration&ssr=false) migration tool, while exporting the tickets I got this warning:
[image: The displayed warning]

I mapped the users to the "users.txt" file in this format:

```
AccountId = user email on ADO
```

Can anyone help to solve this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the FAQ in the following link:

https://github.com/solidify/jira-azuredevops-migrator/blob/master/docs/faq.md

> How to migrate correct user from Jira to Azure DevOps and assign to
> the new work items ?
>
> - User mapping differes between Jira Cloud and Jira Server. To migrate    users and assign the new work items in Azure DevOps to the
>   same user    as the original task had in Jira, we need to add a text
>   file in the    root that would look something like this:
> - When using Jira Cloud then firstly make sure in the config the    '"using-jira-cloud": true' is set. The mapping file the should have
>   accountId/email value pairs. To use email value pairs the users email
>   should be set to public in the user profile in Jira Cloud otherwise
>   the tool cant get the email and will use accountId instead for
>   mapping.
>
>   `Some.JiraUser@domain.com=Some.AzureDevOpsUser@domain.com or JiraAccountId=Some.AzureDevOpsUser@domain.com`
> - When using Jira Server then firstly make sure in the config the '    "using-jira-cloud": false' is set. The mapping should look like the
>   example below:
>
>   `Some.JiraUser@domain.com=Some.AzureDevOpsUser@domain.com`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using "Jira Cloud" way and I make sure to set "using-jira-cloud": true', and still get the same warning! :(

Comment: Do you use the correct JiraAccountId? Have you tried set users email to public in the user profile in Jira Cloud?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: sorry for the late response, Yes I think "Set users email to public", is the solution for my issue, thanks :)